# NVD3 Charts 'No Data' message not centered

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using the latest version of `NVD3`, along with the recommended version of `D3` from the NVD3 Github. I've noticed that on the `discreetBar`, `multiBar` and `pieCharts`, if not others, the `No Data` labels are not exactly centered. They are pushed off to the right a little bit.

I've been playing around in the code a little bit, but still haven't found a working fix.

The code that controls the positioning as found in multiBarChart.js

```
if (!data || !data.length || !data.filter(function(d) { return d.values.length }).length) {
    var noDataText = container.selectAll('.nv-noData').data([noData]);

    noDataText.enter().append('text')
      .attr('class', 'nvd3 nv-noData')
      .attr('dy', '-.7em')
      .style('text-anchor', 'middle');

    noDataText
      .attr('x', margin.left + availableWidth / 2)
      .attr('y', margin.top + availableHeight / 2)
      .text(function(d) { return d });

    return chart;
} else {
    container.selectAll('.nv-noData').remove();
}
```

**Update**
A workaround that seems to be working for all the charts I am using is to have a matching `rmargin right`. By default, some of the charts have a `left` and `bottom` padding of `100`. Adding a `right: 100` will leave the `noData` messages (much closer to) dead centre.

Comment: The code is still leaving room for the top and left margins, and centering the message in the remaining space. You could add in a statement to select "text.nv-noData" and reposition it if it exists, but you'd need custom code to figure out the width and height yourself. It would be easier to just change the source code! You could create an issue on the NVD3 github suggesting they change it. Since they don't draw the axes and legends when there is no data, there's really no need to leave space for them!

Comment: Exactly. I've tried some variations of using only `availableWidth /2` and `controlWidth() / 2` but with no luck. One alternative I've come up with is to remove the `noData` text all together, and to just use a `div` of my own so I have full control over it. Good idea about submitting an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed the  lines 1519-1542 to

```
nv.utils.noData = function(chart, container) {
var opt = chart.options(),
    margin = opt.margin(),
    noData = opt.noData(),
    data = (noData == null) ? ["No Data Available."] : [noData],
    height = nv.utils.availableHeight(opt.height(), container, margin),
    width = nv.utils.availableWidth(opt.width(), container, margin),
    x = margin.left + width/2,
    y = margin.top + height/2;

//Remove any previously created chart components
container.selectAll('g').remove();

var noDataText = container.selectAll('.nv-noData').data(data);

noDataText.enter().append('text')
    .attr('class', 'nvd3 nv-noData')
    .style('text-anchor', 'middle');

noDataText
    .attr('x', '50%')
    .attr('y', '50%')
    .text(function(t){ return t; });
```

In combination with following CSS:

```
.nvd3.nv-noData {
position: relative;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
font-size: 24px;
color: #666;
font-weight: 200;
text-align: center;}
```

I have currently perfect centered no-data texts for all my charts (bar-charts, pie-charts, multibar, sunburst and area charts)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is by adding a css rule in your global style file (no need to edit the js library), quite similar to the phkdev rule, but the most important is here :

```
:host >>> .nv-noData {
  position: relative;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Edit : make sure you have the noData parameters in your chart options